# Почему не отображается SVG спрайт подключенный через css?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Не отображаются svg иконки подключенные через css, которые находятся в svg спрайте. Подключаю через относительный путь. Спрайт находится в папке img, которая находится на одном уровне с index.html. В чем может проблема? Если вам неудобен такой вид кода вот ссылка на [GitHub Pages](https://justdenis.github.io/goit-fe-course/html-css/module-10/index.html)

```js
//Код спрайта

<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-basket" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M31.513 9.179h0.002l-4.4 9.778c-0.217 0.482-0.686 0.825-1.239 0.862v0l-12.672 0.844 0.732 2.091h13.797c1.62 0 2.933 1.314 2.933 2.935 0 1.62-1.314 2.933-2.933 2.933s-2.933-1.314-2.933-2.933h-13.689c0 1.62-1.314 2.933-2.933 2.933s-2.933-1.314-2.933-2.933c0-1.621 1.314-2.935 2.933-2.935h2.651l-5.646-16.132h-3.36c-0.811 0-1.467-0.658-1.467-1.467 0-0.811 0.656-1.467 1.467-1.467h4.4c0.64 0 1.179 0.412 1.38 0.983l0.005-0.002 0.853 2.441h21.717c0.811 0 1.467 0.656 1.467 1.467 0 0.213-0.048 0.416-0.132 0.601zM9.488 10.044l2.711 7.746 12.603-0.841 3.108-6.905h-18.421z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-book" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M31.065 25.889l-14.471 5.988c-0.182 0.079-0.383 0.123-0.594 0.123s-0.412-0.044-0.594-0.123l-14.471-5.988c-0.548-0.223-0.935-0.761-0.935-1.389v-23c0-0.829 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5 0.203 0 0.397 0.041 0.573 0.114h0.001l0.002 0.001c0.004 0.001 0.009 0.004 0.013 0.005l13.911 5.756 13.911-5.756c0.004-0.001 0.009-0.004 0.013-0.005l0.003-0.001c0.176-0.073 0.37-0.114 0.573-0.114 0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5v23c0 0.628-0.387 1.166-0.935 1.389zM14.5 8.503l-11.5-4.759v19.753l11.5 4.759v-19.753zM29 3.744l-11.5 4.759v19.753l11.5-4.759v-19.753zM19.879 10.634l5.5-2.5c0.189-0.086 0.399-0.134 0.621-0.134 0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5 0 0.607-0.361 1.129-0.879 1.365v0l-5.5 2.5c-0.19 0.087-0.4 0.135-0.621 0.135-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5 0-0.607 0.361-1.13 0.879-1.366zM19.879 16.134v0l5.5-2.5c0.189-0.086 0.399-0.134 0.621-0.134 0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.499 0 0.608-0.361 1.13-0.879 1.366l-5.5 2.5c-0.19 0.086-0.4 0.135-0.621 0.135-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5 0-0.607 0.361-1.13 0.879-1.366zM19.879 21.634v0l5.5-2.5c0.189-0.086 0.399-0.134 0.621-0.134 0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5 0 0.607-0.361 1.129-0.879 1.365v0l-5.5 2.5c-0.19 0.087-0.4 0.135-0.621 0.135-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5 0-0.607 0.361-1.13 0.879-1.366zM6 8c0.221 0 0.431 0.048 0.621 0.134v0l5.5 2.5c0.518 0.236 0.879 0.759 0.879 1.366 0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5-0.222 0-0.432-0.048-0.621-0.135v0l-5.5-2.5c-0.518-0.236-0.879-0.758-0.879-1.365 0-0.829 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5zM6 13.5c0.221 0 0.431 0.048 0.621 0.134v0l5.5 2.5c0.518 0.236 0.879 0.759 0.879 1.366 0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5-0.222 0-0.432-0.049-0.621-0.135v0l-5.5-2.5c-0.518-0.236-0.879-0.758-0.879-1.366 0-0.828 0.672-1.499 1.5-1.499zM6 19c0.221 0 0.431 0.048 0.621 0.134v0l5.5 2.5c0.518 0.236 0.879 0.759 0.879 1.366 0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5-0.222 0-0.432-0.048-0.621-0.135v0l-5.5-2.5c-0.518-0.236-0.879-0.758-0.879-1.365 0-0.829 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-clock" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.74 10.003c-1.584-3.696-4.547-6.66-8.243-8.243 1-0.787 2.258-1.26 3.629-1.26 3.244 0 5.874 2.63 5.874 5.874 0 1.371-0.473 2.629-1.26 3.629zM30.5 16.5c0 3.852-1.512 7.343-3.963 9.94l2.029 2.028c0.268 0.269 0.434 0.639 0.434 1.049 0 0.819-0.664 1.483-1.483 1.483-0.41 0-0.781-0.166-1.049-0.435l-2.178-2.178c-2.351 1.642-5.205 2.613-8.29 2.613-3.079 0-5.928-0.966-8.276-2.603l-2.163 2.163c-0.272 0.272-0.647 0.44-1.061 0.44-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.501 0-0.413 0.168-0.789 0.439-1.060l2.012-2.012c-2.443-2.595-3.951-6.082-3.951-9.927 0-8.008 6.492-14.5 14.5-14.5s14.5 6.492 14.5 14.5zM16 5c-6.351 0-11.5 5.148-11.5 11.5 0 6.351 5.149 11.5 11.5 11.5s11.5-5.149 11.5-11.5c0-6.352-5.149-11.5-11.5-11.5zM22 18h-6c-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5v-8c0-0.828 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5 0.672 1.5 1.5v6.499h4.5c0.828 0 1.5 0.672 1.5 1.501 0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zM1.287 10.205c-0.804-1.020-1.287-2.305-1.287-3.705 0-3.314 2.686-6 6-6 1.4 0 2.685 0.483 3.706 1.287-3.775 1.617-6.802 4.644-8.419 8.418z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-computer" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30 25h-9.5v2.499l2 2.001v0.5h-13v-0.5l2-2.001v-2.499h-9.5c-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.501v-19.999c0-0.829 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5h28c0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5v19.999c0 0.829-0.672 1.501-1.5 1.501zM29.5 4h-27v17h27v-17zM13 11c0.414 0 0.789 0.168 1.061 0.439v0l0.939 0.939 2.939-2.939c0.272-0.272 0.647-0.439 1.061-0.439 0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5 0 0.414-0.168 0.789-0.439 1.061v0l-4 4c-0.272 0.271-0.647 0.439-1.061 0.439s-0.789-0.168-1.061-0.439v0l-2-2.001c-0.271-0.271-0.439-0.646-0.439-1.060 0-0.829 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-facebook" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M22.879 0.245c0 1.817 0 5.072 0 5.072s-3.738-0.373-4.674 1.060c-0.512 0.783-0.208 3.077-0.254 4.724 1.632 0 3.327 0 4.959 0-0.418 1.925-0.719 3.23-1.028 4.896-1.412 0-3.958 0-3.958 0v15.759c0 0-4.673 0-6.87 0 0.001-4.858-0.001-10.526 0-15.697-1.067 0-1.856 0-2.923 0 0-1.817 0-3.14 0-4.958 1.035 0 1.855 0 2.891 0 0.148-3.626 0.203-7.217 2.005-9.046 2.023-2.057 3.954-1.809 9.852-1.809z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-frame" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.5 32h-29c-0.829 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5v-29c0-0.829 0.671-1.5 1.5-1.5h29c0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5v29c0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zM29 3h-26v26h26v-26zM6.5 4.5h5.5c0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5s-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5v0h-4.5v4.5c0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5v0-7.5h2zM4.5 20v0c0-0.829 0.672-1.501 1.5-1.501s1.5 0.672 1.5 1.501v0 4.499l4.5 0.001c0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5 0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5v0h-7.5v-7.5zM20 4.5v0h7.5v7.5c0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5v0-4.5h-4.5c-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5s0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5zM20 24.5v-0.001h4.5v-4.499c0-0.829 0.672-1.501 1.5-1.501s1.5 0.672 1.5 1.501v0 7.5h-7.5c-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5 0-0.829 0.672-1.5 1.5-1.5z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-graph" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.5 32h-29c-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5v-29.001c0-0.827 0.672-1.499 1.5-1.499h29c0.828 0 1.5 0.672 1.5 1.499v29.001c0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5zM29 3h-26v26h26v-26zM5.215 16.239v-0.002l4-2.498c0.229-0.141 0.497-0.222 0.785-0.222 0.311 0 0.6 0.095 0.84 0.257l0.006-0.008 6.631 4.42 7.638-5.391c0.248-0.182 0.554-0.29 0.885-0.29 0.828 0 1.5 0.672 1.5 1.5 0 0.5-0.245 0.943-0.622 1.216h0.001l-8.501 6c-0.246 0.179-0.55 0.284-0.878 0.284-0.321 0-0.618-0.101-0.861-0.272l-6.657-4.438-3.135 1.96c-0.241 0.165-0.533 0.262-0.847 0.262-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5 0-0.541 0.286-1.014 0.715-1.278z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-home" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M32 17c0 0.828-0.672 1.499-1.5 1.499-0.395 0-0.752-0.155-1.020-0.405l-0.003 0.004-13.477-13.476-13.447 13.446c-0.271 0.267-0.643 0.431-1.053 0.431-0.828 0-1.5-0.671-1.5-1.499 0-0.425 0.177-0.808 0.461-1.081l14.458-14.459c0.273-0.283 0.656-0.46 1.081-0.46v0 0c0 0 0 0 0.001 0 0.026 0 0.052 0 0.079 0.002 0.004 0 0.008 0.001 0.012 0.001 0.023 0.001 0.045 0.003 0.068 0.005 0.001 0 0.002 0 0.004 0.001 0.367 0.040 0.694 0.212 0.933 0.468l0.001-0.001 5.902 5.902v-1.378c0-0.829 0.671-1.5 1.5-1.5 0.828 0 1.5 0.671 1.5 1.5v4.378l5.598 5.598-0.004 0.004c0.25 0.268 0.406 0.625 0.406 1.020zM29 19.5v10.5c0 0.828-0.672 1.5-1.5 1.5h-3v-12h-6v12h-14c-0.828 0-1.5-0.672-1.5-1.5v-10.5l13-13 13 13zM13.5 19.5h-6v6h6v-6z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-instagram" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M27.938 31.754h-23.631c-2.175 0-3.938-1.764-3.938-3.94v-23.63c0-2.176 1.764-3.94 3.938-3.94h23.631c2.175 0 3.938 1.764 3.938 3.94v23.63c0 2.176-1.764 3.94-3.938 3.94zM16.123 9.894c-2.457 0-4.567 1.455-5.536 3.545h-0.006c-0.010 0.022-0.017 0.046-0.027 0.068-0.058 0.129-0.108 0.262-0.158 0.395-0.023 0.065-0.049 0.128-0.070 0.192-0.046 0.138-0.082 0.277-0.117 0.418-0.017 0.065-0.037 0.13-0.052 0.197-0.032 0.149-0.054 0.3-0.075 0.453-0.009 0.062-0.021 0.122-0.028 0.185-0.022 0.214-0.036 0.432-0.036 0.654 0 3.371 2.734 6.103 6.105 6.103s6.105-2.732 6.105-6.103c0-0.222-0.014-0.439-0.036-0.654-0.007-0.063-0.020-0.123-0.028-0.185-0.021-0.153-0.043-0.304-0.075-0.453-0.015-0.066-0.034-0.132-0.052-0.197-0.034-0.142-0.071-0.281-0.117-0.418-0.021-0.064-0.047-0.127-0.070-0.192-0.049-0.133-0.1-0.266-0.158-0.395-0.010-0.022-0.017-0.046-0.027-0.068h-0.006c-0.969-2.090-3.079-3.545-5.536-3.545zM28.332 5.365c0-0.87-0.705-1.574-1.575-1.574h-3.151c-0.87 0-1.575 0.704-1.575 1.574v3.152c0 0.87 0.705 1.575 1.575 1.575h3.151c0.87 0 1.575-0.705 1.575-1.575v-3.152zM28.332 13.439h-2.905c0.224 0.816 0.345 1.675 0.345 2.561 0 5.329-4.32 9.648-9.649 9.648s-9.649-4.319-9.649-9.648c0-0.886 0.121-1.745 0.345-2.561h-2.905v13.194c0 0.871 0.705 1.577 1.575 1.577h21.268c0.87 0 1.575-0.705 1.575-1.577v-13.194z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-pinterest" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M14.217 20.743c-0.257 1.025-0.517 2.1-0.785 3.151-0.265 1.036-0.498 2.087-0.884 3.040-0.639 1.577-1.45 3.1-2.514 4.334-0.708 0.821-0.558 0.494-0.77 0.449-0.162-0.034-0.176-0.193-0.208-0.425-0.174-1.253-0.055-2.702 0.009-4.11 0.074-1.605 0.411-2.939 0.725-4.272 0.596-2.54 1.164-5.030 1.766-7.586 0.039-0.17 0.148-0.45 0.111-0.548-0.273-0.71-0.45-1.348-0.528-2.094-0.090-0.855-0.021-1.654 0.171-2.391 0.341-1.302 1.124-2.455 2.331-2.878 0.768-0.266 1.618-0.145 2.135 0.162 0.532 0.319 0.897 0.821 1.067 1.534 0.182 0.757 0.048 1.663-0.098 2.327-0.329 1.5-0.761 2.626-1.153 4.074-0.194 0.718-0.415 1.455-0.233 2.23 0.167 0.711 0.538 1.201 1.042 1.569 0.524 0.382 1.145 0.59 2 0.56 1.511-0.053 2.561-1.019 3.263-1.93 1.124-1.458 1.803-3.426 2.062-5.767 0.082-0.756 0.144-1.623 0.086-2.479-0.108-1.58-0.602-2.852-1.387-3.836-0.746-0.939-1.804-1.685-3.092-2.106-1.276-0.416-3.042-0.555-4.612-0.287-2.853 0.489-4.864 2.11-6.049 4.348-0.62 1.172-1.030 2.519-1.030 4.197 0 1.294 0.319 2.295 0.834 3.077 0.164 0.247 0.404 0.452 0.564 0.735 0.228 0.401-0.034 0.998-0.146 1.433-0.135 0.523-0.15 1.246-0.761 1.258-0.254 0.005-0.571-0.18-0.785-0.299-1.606-0.887-2.581-2.502-2.981-4.596-0.244-1.273-0.242-2.756 0-3.985 0.234-1.19 0.67-2.287 1.153-3.177 1.002-1.85 2.47-3.329 4.257-4.385 1.374-0.812 2.923-1.382 4.809-1.657 0.625-0.091 1.273-0.129 1.975-0.162 2.053-0.096 3.919 0.369 5.324 0.997 1.483 0.663 2.667 1.546 3.668 2.641 1.031 1.126 1.782 2.436 2.257 4.073 0.249 0.852 0.49 1.762 0.49 2.815 0 1.056-0.223 1.985-0.379 2.914-0.583 3.481-2.239 6.327-4.724 7.948-0.602 0.391-1.33 0.754-2.159 0.996-0.821 0.239-1.758 0.418-2.761 0.348-0.974-0.066-1.771-0.331-2.441-0.71-0.665-0.375-1.223-0.836-1.62-1.531z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-search" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.786 26.636c0.53 0.53 0.859 1.264 0.859 2.075 0 1.62-1.314 2.933-2.933 2.933-0.811 0-1.543-0.329-2.075-0.86v0l-8.597-8.596c-1.746 1.031-3.776 1.634-5.95 1.634-6.48 0-11.733-5.253-11.733-11.733s5.253-11.733 11.733-11.733c6.48 0 11.733 5.253 11.733 11.733 0 2.174-0.603 4.204-1.634 5.95l8.597 8.597zM12.089 3.287c-4.86 0-8.8 3.941-8.8 8.802s3.94 8.8 8.8 8.8c4.86 0 8.8-3.94 8.8-8.8s-3.94-8.802-8.8-8.802z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-twitter" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M21.554 3.201c2.503-0.044 3.836 0.868 5.109 2.027 1.081-0.092 2.485-0.695 3.312-1.116 0.267-0.145 0.535-0.293 0.804-0.439-0.473 1.276-1.113 2.276-2.097 3.035-0.219 0.167-0.436 0.395-0.71 0.502 0 0.005 0 0.011 0 0.016 1.403-0.014 2.56-0.647 3.659-0.991 0 0.005 0 0.011 0 0.016-0.577 0.917-1.359 1.849-2.192 2.516-0.336 0.267-0.673 0.534-1.009 0.801 0.018 1.486-0.022 2.903-0.299 4.151-1.615 7.255-5.893 12.181-12.663 14.292-2.432 0.757-6.361 1.068-9.147 0.377-1.381-0.342-2.629-0.73-3.799-1.242-0.651-0.284-1.254-0.592-1.83-0.944-0.19-0.114-0.378-0.23-0.567-0.345 0.628 0.018 1.364 0.192 2.065 0.078 0.636-0.102 1.259-0.075 1.846-0.203 1.462-0.321 2.761-0.746 3.878-1.401 0.543-0.318 1.366-0.689 1.751-1.147-0.726 0.012-1.385-0.156-1.924-0.346-2.091-0.738-3.308-2.096-4.101-4.135 0.634 0.070 2.459 0.235 2.886-0.126-0.798-0.044-1.564-0.506-2.113-0.849-1.682-1.052-3.054-2.817-3.044-5.534 0.222 0.105 0.442 0.209 0.662 0.314 0.423 0.178 0.853 0.273 1.356 0.378 0.213 0.044 0.639 0.169 0.884 0.078-0.011 0-0.021 0-0.032 0-0.325-0.378-0.855-0.63-1.183-1.038-1.079-1.34-2.090-3.404-1.451-5.863 0.162-0.624 0.42-1.174 0.694-1.682 0.011 0.005 0.021 0.010 0.032 0.015 0.126 0.263 0.406 0.457 0.583 0.677 0.551 0.683 1.231 1.297 1.924 1.839 2.361 1.846 4.486 2.981 7.9 3.82 0.866 0.214 1.867 0.377 2.902 0.378-0.29-0.846-0.197-2.215 0.031-3.034 0.576-2.060 1.825-3.543 3.659-4.34 0.438-0.19 0.924-0.329 1.435-0.441 0.263-0.031 0.526-0.063 0.789-0.094z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

```css
.section-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-item {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 33.333%;
  padding-left: 6rem;
  padding-bottom: 10rem;
}

.list-item:nth-child(1n+4) {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.list-item__icon--clock::before,
.list-item__icon--graph::before,
.list-item__icon--computer::before,
.list-item__icon--book::before,
.list-item__icon--home::before,
.list-item__icon--frame::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-clock');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
}

.list-item__icon--clock::before {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-clock');
}

.list-item__icon--graph::before {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-graph');
}

.list-item__icon--computer::before {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-computer');
}

.list-item__icon--book::before {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-book');
}

.list-item__icon--home::before {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-home');
}

.list-item__icon--frame::before {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sprite.svg#icon-frame');
}

.list-item__name {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.list-item__text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-list">
  <div class="list-item list-item__icon--clock">
    <h2 class="list-item__name">PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
    <p class="list-item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem omnis nulla fuga.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item list-item__icon--graph">
    <h2 class="list-item__name">WEB DESIGN</h2>
    <p class="list-item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem omnis nulla fuga.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item list-item__icon--computer">
    <h2 class="list-item__name">CREATIVITY</h2>
    <p class="list-item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem omnis nulla fuga.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item list-item__icon--book">
    <h2 class="list-item__name">SEO</h2>
    <p class="list-item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem omnis nulla fuga.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item list-item__icon--home">
    <h2 class="list-item__name">CSS/HTML</h2>
    <p class="list-item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem omnis nulla fuga.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item list-item__icon--frame">
    <h2 class="list-item__name">DIGITAL</h2>
    <p class="list-item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem omnis nulla fuga.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: оно так не будет работать, поместите ваш svg выше `<!doctype html>` и через `use` вызывайте ваши иконки ...

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно чтоб свг загружалось через css, а не через html

Comment: если через css то надо отдельные картинки ...я раньше сколько пробовал это работало только в chrome а вообще symbol чуть чуть не для этого применяется

Comment: на самом деле можно но только не через css а если использовать `<use xlink:href="file.svg#icon" />` но сработает это только от http другими словами от file:/// не сработает ..будет `shadow closed`